# Any way to skip unwanted file in Aria2 before download?

Tags: aria2

I am using aria2 on a router with openwrt.

I had tried to download a torrent file including some files with the size of filename over 255 bytes.
Because of the filename being too long , my ext4 storage space does not support downloading the file.

I had unselected the files with too long filename before downloading.
It seemed no matter whether the file was unselected,aria2 would check all files inside the torrent files
So,the downloading still failed because aria2 detected that there were some files with too long filename.

Is there any way to skip the files with too long filename inside the torrent file?